# Mtp android mount

Tags: 14.04, android, mtp

Using my Android Lg G2 I have been trying to mount via mtp and have not found an easy way. Does anyone have a simple solution to this problem?

Edit: looking for a GUI application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setup this

```
sudo apt-get install mtpfs
sudo mkdir -m 775 /media/onex
sudo mtpfs -o allow_other /media/onex
gksudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

and add the following line:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"
```

and then (back in terminal):

```
sudo service udev restart
```

More detailed guide and How to do it , chk this [XDA Post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2055563&__utma=248941774.1188052748.1406691811.1406691811.1406691811.1&__utmb=248941774.1.10.1406691811&__utmc=248941774&__utmx=-&__utmz=248941774.1406691811.1.1.utmcsr=google%7Cutmccn=(organic)%7Cutmcmd=organic%7Cutmctr=(not%20provided)&__utmv=-&__utmk=269183986)

Comment: After the third line, one gets:
Unable to open ~/.mtpz-data for reading, MTPZ disabled.Listing raw device(s)
No raw devices found.